# Encrypting data between NRF24L01 using AES

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

I am trying to send encrypted data using AES  via a pair of NRF24L01 and two Arduino Uno boards. I have made two sketches but can not get it working.

The used library for AES:

[enter link description here](https://github.com/DavyLandman/AESLib)

Transmitter code:

```
// TrackControl - the master or the transmitter

 // http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/

 //~ - CONNECTIONS: nRF24L01 Modules See:
 //~ http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo
 //~ 1 - GND
 //~ 2 - VCC 3.3V !!! NOT 5V
 //~ 3 - CE to Arduino pin 9
 //~ 4 - CSN to Arduino pin 10
 //~ 5 - SCK to Arduino pin 13
 //~ 6 - MOSI to Arduino pin 11
 //~ 7 - MISO to Arduino pin 12
 //~ 8 - UNUSED

#include <SPI.h>
//~ #include <TMRh20nRF24L01.h>
//~ #include <TMRh20RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <AESLib.h>


#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10
uint8_t key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};

// NOTE: the "LL" at the end of the constant is "LongLong" type
// These are the IDs of each of the slaves
const uint64_t slaveID[2] = {0xE8E8F0F0E1LL, 0xE8E8F0F0E2LL} ;

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN); // Create a Radio

char  dataToSend[]="123456789012345";

unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long prevMillis;
unsigned long txIntervalMillis = 1000;
int txVal = 0;
float ackMessg[2]={1,2};
byte ackMessgLen = 4; // NB this 4 is the number of bytes in the 2 ints that will be recieved


void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Track Control Starting");
    radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
    radio.enableAckPayload();
    radio.setRetries(10,5); // delay, count
}

//====================

void loop() {

    currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - prevMillis >= txIntervalMillis) {

    radio.openWritingPipe(slaveID[0]); // calls the first slave
                                        // there could be a FOR loop to call several slaves in turn
    aes256_enc_single(key, dataToSend);

    bool rslt;
    rslt = radio.write( dataToSend, sizeof(dataToSend) );
    Serial.print("\nRSLT (1 = success) ");
    Serial.println(rslt);

    if ( radio.isAckPayloadAvailable() ) {
        radio.read(ackMessg,ackMessgLen);
        Serial.print("Acknowledge received: ");
        Serial.print(ackMessg[0]);
        Serial.print("  ");
        Serial.println(ackMessg[1]);
    }
    prevMillis = millis();
 }
}
```

Receiver code:

```
// HandController - the slave or the receiver

    // http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/

    //~ - CONNECTIONS: nRF24L01 Modules See:
    //~ http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo
    //~ 1 - GND
    //~ 2 - VCC 3.3V !!! NOT 5V
    //~ 3 - CE to Arduino pin 9
    //~ 4 - CSN to Arduino pin 10
    //~ 5 - SCK to Arduino pin 13
    //~ 6 - MOSI to Arduino pin 11
    //~ 7 - MISO to Arduino pin 12
    //~ 8 - UNUSED

#include <SPI.h>
//~ #include <TMRh20nRF24L01.h>
//~ #include <TMRh20RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

#include <AESLib.h>

#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10

// NOTE: the "LL" at the end of the constant is "LongLong" type

const uint64_t   deviceID = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL; // Define the ID for this slave
uint8_t key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};

int valChange = 1;

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);

char  dataReceived[32];
int ackData[2] = {12,23};

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Hand Controller Starting");
    radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
    radio.openReadingPipe(1,deviceID);
    radio.enableAckPayload();
    radio.writeAckPayload(1, ackData, sizeof(ackData));
    radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {

    if ( radio.available() ) {
        radio.read( dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived) );
        radio.writeAckPayload(1, ackData, sizeof(ackData));
         for (int x = 0; x <32; x++) {
      //if (dataReceived[x] < 16) {
      //  Serial.write('0');
    // }

    //  Serial.print(dataReceived[x]);}
    // Serial.println();


        ackData[0] += valChange; // this just increments so you can see that new data is being sent
    }
   aes256_dec_single(key, dataReceived);
    Serial.println("decrypted:");
    Serial.println(dataReceived);
}}
```

I cannot receive the same message after decryption.

Comment: attach your output here so we have better understanding what is the issue.

Comment: i got strange characters at the receiver side
when i test AES encryption/decryption a lone without nRf24l01 i receive the input data normally after decryption 
when i use nRF24l01 without encryption decryption i receive the sent data on the receiver side normally

Comment: `aes256_dec_single` requires `dataToSend` to be 256 bits as-well. From what I know, AES only works on multiples of block sizes. It can't handle variable length data. The way to work around that is to pad the data with, for example, zeros, till it's a multiple of the block size.

Comment: I still think serial terminal output will help us for better understanding.